# Is there a tool like fs_usage that will show the specific bytes being read or written?

Tags: macos, filesystems, debug

Working on a project to reverse-engineer Mail applications changes to keychain files. Using fs_usage I can see # of bytes written to keychain file, but I am unable to determine dynamically exactly what content is being changed

Thoughts, approaches very much appreciated/

thanks,
LightworksGal

Comment: You really should mention your OS on questions like these. From `fs_usage`, `keychain` and `Mail`, I infer Mac OS X, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ktrace` or `dtrace` will let you see reads and writes to files on OSX (`strace` is the linux equivalent), among a lot more data you'll need to filter out.

Comment: Is there an `strace` port to OSX? Natively I only know of [dtrace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtrace.1.html).

Comment: @Gilles edited my answer to point to ktrace instead of strace

Comment: There is no `ktrace` on my OS X 10.6 system.  It was replaced by `dtrace` in 10.5.  http://support.apple.com/kb/TA24816